# mongodb findAndModify causes many write conflicts which causes 100% CPU usage

Tags: mongodb, go, transactions

I’m using mongo DB with official [golang driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) as a storage for batch processing documents in a background.
DB setup is: 1 primary and 2 secondaries.

Each document in `processing` collection has given structure:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("6239ba1f4f6a3f8e20d16243"),
    data: { ... },
    created_at: ISODate("2022-03-22T11:59:27.795Z"),
    processed_times: 1,
    status: 2, // status of processing (new, failed, in_progress)
    updated_at: ISODate("2022-03-22T11:59:27.795Z"),
    last_picked_at: ISODate("2022-03-22T11:59:32.164Z") // date of last "pick" for processing
}
```

Current flow of documents processing in that collection looks like this:

1. Consumer (separate process) reads messages from event bus and writes them into processing collection as documents with status `new`
2. Processor (separate worker process) with a little timeout “picks” 50 documents with status `new` from `processing` collection. Basically, it runs a loop until 50 documents (or less if no more is presented in a collection) retrieved for processing. The query for “picking” each document is:

```
{
      findAndModify: 'processing',
      new: true,
      query: { status: 0, last_picked_at: { '$exists': false } },
      sort: { _id: 1 },
      update: {
        '$set': {
          status: 2,
          last_picked_at: current_date
        },
        '$inc': { processed_times: 1 }
}
```

UPD: I'm using `findAndModify` in a loop because mongo DB doesn't have sql-like `select for update` with lock for multiple entries. There are multiple instances of worker and I needed some built-in lock mechanism for picking documents. Also, I can't fetch only one entry because later on process service must retrieve additional information about these documents by sending their IDs to another service in batch handler. Pseudo-code of processing documents:

```
// pick items
itemsToProcess = []
for i to 50
  item = findAndModify(...)
  if item is not found:
    break
  else:
    itemsToProcess[] = item
endfor

// run business logic which processes items and adds data into it
failedToProcess = processPickedItems(itemsToProcess)
if failedToProcess is not empty:
  // returns all failed items back to processing collection to re-process
  for failedItem in failedToProcess:
    returnItemToProcessing(failedItem)
  endfor

run transaction:
  save items in different collection
  delete successfully processed items
```

3. After fetching all the documents each of them is processed and service runs a transaction, where it stores all processed documents in a different collection and removes all processed documents from `processing` collection.

All the operations (including transactions) have following read/write concerns:

```
write - {w: majority, j: false}
read - majority
```

When we ran service everything was fine, but on 4th day of work we noticed burst of conflict updates from findAndModify operation which picks documents for processing, the CPU usage of primary was 100% and execution time of such operations was getting higher and higher. We switched over the primary node and the overload has gone, but then we’ve experienced the same behaviour after 5 days.
I’ve tried to understand what is wrong with the code and why there are such bursts of write conflicts after a long period of normal work without much conflicts, but i’ve ran out of guesses.

What would you suggest to identify potential causes for such case?

Comment: How many documents are in the collection and do you have an index on `status` and `last_picked_at`. It's possible that over the last few days you've added enough documents that without an index, MongoDB is forced to perform full collection scans and sorts.

Comment: @ClarkMcCauley index for status + last_picked_at exists and I've checked all indexes usage before first deploy. Currently findAndModify uses this index as `explain` shows. The structure of index: `{ status: 1, last_picked_at: 1 }`.

About the number of documents - worker is clearing `processing` collection much faster than consumer writes documents to it, so the average number of documents in collection in a moment is ~20-50. When bursts of conflicts happen we see that time of each findAndModify increases from 10ms to 40-50 mins within a day if primary node is not switched over.

Comment: Are you using MongoDB Atlas by chance? They have a real-time operation viewer that shows which database operations are taking the most time to run which in my experience has helped identify why there's such high resource usage. Have you tried this?

Comment: Unfortunately, we're using simple mongodb hosted within own data centers. My guess is that somehow there are infinite retries of resolving write conflicts inside mongo and that's what causes high cpu usage and throttles other concurrent operations..

Comment: Its not clear why you are using a `findAndModify` in a for-loop. You may want to include some code or atleast the pseudo-code of the process for steps 2 and 3.

Comment: @prasad_ updated question with the reason of using `findAndModify` and some pseudo-code